# What is the purpose of the underscore in _(node)->Execute() for c++

Tags: c++

The underscore, in this case, is not part of the identifier. The code I'm seeing looks like

```
for(auto nodeItr = myNodes.begin(); nodeItr != myNodes.end(); nodeItr++) {
    auto node = *nodeItr;
    int status = _(node)->Execute();
    if (status != 0) return -1;
}
```

Comment: I am guessing there is a `typedef`, a `using`, a function definition or a macro definition called `_` somewhere.

Comment: if that is the case, I'm going to shoot the individual who did that... but admittedly,I hadn't thought of that. Looking now...

Comment: An `_` by itself *is* a valid identifier. You'll just need to figure out where it's declared/defined.

Comment: found it... the _ is an overloaded inline function. Ugh... was thinking something was added in C++11 I was missing. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

There is a series of wrapper functions declared like `NodePtrWrapper* _(...)`

Feeling stupid, but appreciate the responses...

Comment: Just out of interest: what does that function do? Because why would anyone name a function like that.

Comment: The function just does a pointer conversion from the wrapper object to the contained object. By using the `auto` declaration, the type was not really all that obvious, so didn't realize I was dealing with a wrapper class. Still, one character function names is a bit lame.